# Create new page in magnolia cms from Blossom module

Tags: magnolia

Could anybody please tell if it is possible using blossom to create new page in Pages and fill it with particular components(and configure components by putting there some variables) ? I would like to do it in the java code.

Best Regards
Jan

Answer (score 1):

Whether with blossom or not, if you can define template with automatically created components so as soon as this template is assigned to a page and page is opened, all auto-created components and areas will be created.

HTH,
Jan